# Calculating Value Of Trigonometric Formula

Tags: trigonometry

when $~\tan\theta+\sin\theta=\dfrac{1}{2}$, evaluate $~(\sin^{2}\theta-\sin 2\theta)$
is it possible to get the exact value?

I got $~\sin^{2}\theta-\sin 2\theta=\dfrac{\tan^{2}\theta-2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^{2}\theta}$, but can't calculate it more.

Comment: can you pls check that you have written the problem correctly.

Comment: it is impossible to get exact value without numeric calculation as there is two results. one is .606 and another is .768.

Comment: I checked it. it's written correctly.

Answer (score 1):

$\large \tan \theta + \sin \theta=\frac{1}{2} $; Squaring we get

$\large\tan^2 \theta+2.\sin \theta.\tan \theta+\sin^2 \theta=\frac{1}{4}$

$\large\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}+2.\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos\theta}+\sin^2 \theta=\frac{1}{4}$

$\large\sin^2\theta[\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}+2.\frac{1}{\cos\theta}+1]=\frac{1}{4}$

$\large\sin^2\theta[\frac{1+2.\cos\theta+\cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}]=\frac{1}{4}$

$\large\sin^2\theta[\frac{(1+\cos\theta)^2}{\cos^2\theta}]=\frac{1}{4}$

$\large\tan\theta.(1+\cos\theta)=\frac{1}{2}$

$\large(\frac{1}{2}-\sin\theta)(1+\cos\theta)=\frac{1}{2}$

$\cos\theta-2.\sin\theta-\sin2\theta=0$

$\sin2\theta=\cos\theta-2.\sin\theta$

put this expression for $\sin2\theta$ into $\sin^2\theta-\sin2\theta$ to get

$\sin^2\theta-\cos\theta+2.\sin\theta+ \color{red}{1-1}$ (making perfect square)

$(\sin\theta+1)^2-(\cos\theta+1)$

Is this what you need?

Comment: no. I want the explicit value.